# Programming assignment says test program will only #include .H file, not .CC file. Can someone clarify

Tags: c, include

So I have 2 files I need to turn in, call them: example.cc and example.h

We've been told that their test code will only #include "example.h"

Normally I've always used #include "example.cc" as this will have already included example.h in it's declaration.

When I run the test code, I simply get "Undefined reference to example::example.." anytime I mention example in the test code, this is obviously because the test code can only see my delcarations in example.h, not their actual implementation.

What am I missing?  I've tried #including example.cc in example.h, but this obviously isn't right.

Comment: Can you tell us wich compiler/environment are you using?

Comment: I'm using g++ for compiling

Comment: And you're quite-sure they don't want a **lib** to go with that header file?

Comment: #including example.cc in example.h shouldn't be a problem as long as the `#include` is at the end of example.h - last line.

Comment: Are there any files besides the ones you need to turn in? Where do you normally #include "example.cc"? What does the g++ command you normally use to compile look like?

Comment: @user93353 this worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't put "solved" in the title. We don't do that here. If you want to mark the question as resolved you accept the answer that solved it. If the answer came in the form of a comment you can ask the commenter to post it as an answer then accept it.

Comment: @user93353, #including the .cc file certainly "works" (for some values of "works"), but is barbarous anyway. See my answer.

Comment: @pledgehollywood Definitely make sure you understand how the files you hand in will be compiled before you check this one off as solved -- it works the way you compile it now, but will it work the way they'll compile it?

Comment: @vonbrand - Sure. But I was just solving the puzzle of why #include wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

It seems likely that your professor has some sort of other file, say professor_main.cc, and that they will compile the project like this:

```
g++ example.cc professor_main.cc -o project
```

Their professor_main.cc will have a line

```
#include "example.h"
```

and it will also use a few of your functions, and likely test that they're doing the right thing:

```
std::cout << (example_add(2,3) == 5) ? "good" : "bad" << std::endl;
```

Now, if they didn't #include example.h, or if you didn't make that file correctly, they would get a compile error on professor_main.cc, because it wouldn't know about example_add(int,int). The crucial line that should be in the header file and that makes this error go away is:

```
int example_add(int a, int b);
```

This is called a function declaration.

If everything's done correctly with the header, but your professor made a mistake and tried to compile the project without example.cc, like this:

```
g++ professor_main.cc -o project
```

Then they would get a *linker* error about an "undefined reference" to example_add().

What's missing is the function *definition*:

```
int example_add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

This should be in your example.cc file, and if the professor includes that on their compilation command line, all should be well.

However, if you did #include "example.cc" in your *header* file, all would not be well. Effectively, you would then have copied-and-pasted example.cc into professor_main.cc, because it's #included there. But it's also obviously still in its own file, example.cc. So if your professor tried to do this:

```
g++ example.cc professor_main.cc -o project
```

They would get a *multiple definition* error from the linker, because the function example_add() would've been defined *twice*.

Generally, then, what you're probably supposed to do is put all your function *definitions* in your source file (.cc) and all your function *declarations* in your header file (.h). Try compiling with another .cc file yourself and experiment to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ (and C, from which it descends) the idea is that *header* files (`*.h` in C, no extension in C++) contain declarations (no executable code, except for inline functions), while code files (`*.c in C,`*.cc`in C++) contain all executable code, and`#include` the headers that declare what they need. Note that the file implementing some funky class for wider use should also include the header where it is declared, to avoid hard to track down bugs due to differing declarations.

The C/C++ preprocessor is a dumb beast, it just replaces text, and `#include` just copies the contents of the file verbatim. So you can do all sorts of weird contortions, like starting a statement in the `#incude`d file ind finish it outside, or include executable code in the header. I will compile  and work fine, but what really matters is if the next human reading the code understands it (and by that I mean *you* in a couple of days). Your TA won't suffer from your badly organized code, she will just wrinkle her nose and give you an F. *You* will, while trying to get it to work.

What they presumably mean is that you should implement, say `class foo`, give the needed declarations to use `class foo` in header file `foo.h` (and *only* what the unwashed masses should see of how `class foo` works!), and a code file `foo.cc` giving the actual implementation; they will supply `bar-uses-foo.cc` which includes `foo.h` and links against `foo.o` to test your class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your compiler to link the file and then build them. Another thing is than in each of the files except the header file, you need to include the header.

something like this should help

```
gcc -c example.c -o example.o
gcc example.o -o example
```

if you add another file that uses the header:

```
gcc -c file1.c -o file1.o 
gcc -c file2.c -o file2.o
gcc file1.o file2.o -o myprogram
```

The terms `gcc` and `g++` are both Linux and Unix compilers. 
if you are using windows dev c++ should work or use [gcc for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394755/how-to-install-gcc-on-windows-7-machine)