# Can't install pycrypto on windows virtualenv

Tags: python, windows, pycrypto

I am trying to install pycrypto on my Windows machine. I have mingw installed and distutils is using it. The error here is what I am getting:

```
In file included from C:\Python27\include/pyconfig.h:68:0,

from C:\Python27\include/Python.h:8,

from src/winrand.c:33:

c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/io.h:301:1: error: unknown type name 'off64_t'

c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/io.h:301:36: error: unknown type name 'off64_t'

c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/io.h:302:1: error: unknown type name 'off64_t'

c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/io.h:302:39: error: unknown type name 'off64_t'

src/winrand.c:38:0: warning: "_WIN32_WINNT" redefined [enabled by default]

In file included from c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/_mingw.h:35:0,

from c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/io.h:27,

from C:\Python27\include/pyconfig.h:68,

from C:\Python27\include/Python.h:8,

from src/winrand.c:33:

c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/sdkddkver.h:154:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Edit: I found this, but I am not sure how to fix pip install with it.
http://ac-archive.sourceforge.net/largefile/largefiles_win32.print.html

Comment: Could it be a 32 vs 64 bit problem, as in you're mixing the two somewhere somehow?

Comment: That's what I thought at first, so I wiped my whole computer and started over and only picked 32-bit items.

Comment: could be relevant: https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed/issues/166

Comment: Any reason why you're not using http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto ?

Comment: I am installing using virtualenv. Even if I used pre-compiled packages, it wouldn't explain this error. Could happen with another package as well.

Comment: I've seen this a few times. There are other similar questions on stack overflow if you do some digging. Otherwise consider installing gcc. Heres a [relevant link for that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394755/how-to-install-gcc-on-windows-7-machine)

Comment: Not all extensions can be built with the mingw32 gcc compiler, because the standard for Python was MSVC++ 2008. Unfortunately, the free Express edition has been retired and is no longer available. See comments for the question [_How do I point easy_install to vcvarsall.bat?_](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6551724/355230).

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem when building Fabric in windows. 
The reason was mingw32's gcc config when building pycrypto.
In configure, gcc's setting -std is set to c99.
But, when -std is c99, **__STRICT_ANSI__** is defined and typedef _off_t off_t and _off64_t off64_t  in "sys/types.h" are skipped.
I succeeded to build pycrypto by modifying sys/types.h in mingw32 but it was brutal.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a virtualenv (I usually put all mine on the desktop)
2. Download the binary of pycrypto (matching your installed python version and architecture - no support for python3 as of now)
              - http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml
3. navigate to the easy_install executable (under `Lib\site-packages`) within the virtualenv folder you created and run the pycrypto install: `easy_install  C:\path\to\the\download\pycrypto-2.6.win-amd64-py2.7.exe`