# Python Module Install GCC Failed

Tags: python

I'm trying to install this Python module but I'm running into problems. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/noise/

Error message:

> command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

I'm on Windows 7, Python 2.7. I found some sites recommending MinGW but that didn't work either. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Any notes on the errors you saw after you installed MinGW?  First guess would be that gcc wasn't in your path . . .

Answer (score 0):

gcc is a c/c++ plus compiler (http://gcc.gnu.org/). This was answered very thoroughly here [how to install gcc on windows 7 machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394755/how-to-install-gcc-on-windows-7-machine).