# How to install G++ 4.9 on windows

Tags: windows, gcc, windows-7, installation, gcc4.9

I know this seems like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394755/how-to-install-gcc-on-windows-7-machine) and many more, but hear me out. That question points to MingGW, which, as far as I can tell, only has version `4.8.whatever` of gcc with it. I tried Cygwin, but [Cygwin never really worked with my IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24112160/1653609).

I'm trying to add the exe for G++ 4.9 to the GNU GCC Compiler that comes with CodeBlocks. I just need the g++.exe for the `#include <regex>`.

Comment: I think that cigwin is the best way for gcc on Windows.
What's your OS ?

Comment: Even with 4.8, invoking g++ with the `-std=c++11` switch should work... Not sure about MinGW...

Comment: @selbie I'm a noob, how would I do that? _(Post as answer please.)_

Comment: Type `g++ -std=c++11 mycode.cpp` at the command line.

Comment: @selbie `cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"`

Comment: Have you considered just using Visual Studio Express?  VS is a free download these days and is largely C++11 compliant.

Comment: @selbie `error C2784: 'bool std::tr1::regex_match(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_StTraits,_StAlloc> &,const std::tr1::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,std::tr1::regex_constants::match_flag_type)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::tr1::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &' from 'const std::string'`

Answer (score 6):

Use the distro from this [site](http://nuwen.net/), they have g++ 4.9.2 which supports

Answer (score 0):

You can install MinGW. It contains GCC and G++

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).