# Codeblocks' Cygwin compiler isn't working

Tags: c++, cygwin, codeblocks, toolchain

Using the default setup for Cygwin with codeblocks, I get the following error.

```
"NameScanner - Debug" uses an invalid compiler. Probably the toolchain path within the compiler options is not setup correctly?! Skipping...
Nothing to be done.
```

I tried their [custom installation instructions](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_Cygwin_Compiler) and that gave me this error on `cstdlib`, a default file

```
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.2\cwchar|249|error: `::wcstold' has not been declared|
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.2\cwchar|265|error: `__gnu_cxx::wcstold' has not been declared|
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.2\cstdlib|181|error: `::strtold' has not been declared|
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.2\cstdlib|200|error: `__gnu_cxx::strtold' has not been declared|
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32\bits\ctype_base.h|44|error: `_UPPER' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32\bits\ctype_base.h|45|error: `_LOWER' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32\bits\ctype_base.h|46|error: `_ALPHA' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32\bits\ctype_base.h|47|error: `_DIGIT' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32\bits\ctype_base.h|48|error: `_HEX' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32\bits\ctype_base.h|49|error: `_SPACE' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32\bits\ctype_base.h|50|error: `_BLANK' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32\bits\ctype_base.h|50|error: `_PUNCT' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32\bits\ctype_base.h|50|error: `_ALPHA' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32\bits\ctype_base.h|50|error: `_DIGIT' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32\bits\ctype_base.h|51|error: `_PUNCT' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32\bits\ctype_base.h|51|error: `_ALPHA' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32\bits\ctype_base.h|51|error: `_DIGIT' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32\bits\ctype_base.h|52|error: `_CONTROL' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32\bits\ctype_base.h|53|error: `_PUNCT' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32\bits\ctype_base.h|54|error: `_ALPHA' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32\bits\ctype_base.h|54|error: `_DIGIT' was not declared in this scope|
C:\...\NameScanner\name.cpp|3|regex: No such file or directory|
C:\...\NameScanner\name.cpp||In constructor `Name::Name(std::string)':|
C:\...\NameScanner\name.cpp|19|error: `regex_match' undeclared (first use this function)|
C:\...\NameScanner\name.cpp|19|error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)|
||=== Build finished: 24 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

*Any* help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you uninstall everything, download [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/13.12/Windows/codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe/download) version of codeblocks and install it. It already comes with everything you need (that would be GCC).