# Rubygems Error - Cannot install eventmachne 1.0.3 on Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using addressable 2.3.6
Using chunky_png 1.3.1
Using fssm 0.2.10
Using sass 3.2.19
Using compass 0.12.7
Using breakpoint 2.0.7
Using timers 1.1.0
Using celluloid 0.15.2
Using coderay 1.1.0
Using compass-blend-modes 0.0.2
Using color-schemer 0.2.8
Using compass-normalize 1.5
Using compass-rgbapng 0.2.1
Using compass-validator 3.0.1
Using css_parser 1.3.5

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/Zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lssl... yes
checking for main() in -lcrypto... yes
checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for openssl/err.h... yes
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... yes
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for sys/event.h... no
creating Makefile

make  clean

make
compiling binder.cpp
make: g++: Command not found
Makefile:198: recipe for target 'binder.o' failed
make: *** [binder.o] Error 127

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/extensions/x86_64-cygwin/1.9.1/eventmachine-1.0.3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.0.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I'm trying to install the missing gems necesary so I can use drush omega-guard

```
There was a problem with your setup:                                 [error]
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler can't satisfy your Gemfile's dependencies.
Install missing gems with `bundle install`.
```

But I get the error with eventmachine, how can I fix this? I tried changing the version of ruby to see if it works, but i just ran into some other errors.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you don't have a C++ compiler. If you're using Ubuntu try `sudo apt-get install g++`.

Comment: How so :) ? Your output has Unix-like path (`/home/Zach/.rvm/...`). Anyway, try using http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/ to install GCC on windows, or you can refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6395050/1856239 .